# Relationship among MSE of three regression models

Tags: mse

Suppose that we fit three regression models (OLS linear regression) with training mean squared error MSE_1, MSE_2, and MSE_3. We know that the first model 1 has first 7 predictors, the second model 2 has additional two more predictors, and the last model has all k predictors (K > 9). What is the relationship among MSE_1, MSE_2 and MSE_3?

Comment: Splendid! Now what do you know about how parameter counts influence OLS performance?

Comment: @Dave I think that's what I'm missing here. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: If you add an extra variable to the model, a variable whose coefficient can be zero, how does the affect the model performance? Hint: Think about what it would mean for that new coefficient to be zero.